# Augmented/Mediated/... reality/virtuality terms - Which one to pick?

Tags: augmented-reality, vocabulary

That might sound a bit off-topic but I think this is actually closely related to programming (in particular to video games), so here we go:

There are a lot of terms used to describe interactions between real world and a virtual one but I have to admit I'm a bit confused about those terms.
As I have to find a suitable title for a project, the question is both specific to a concrete example and general as I'd like to learn the correct "use cases" for those words.

Concrete case: A game, using Kinect sensor to get input from the user and Philips Hue LEDs as the "physical" representation of a game object (e.g. an object turns red in the game, the corresponding LED also turns red).
I tend to think that the proper term would be "augmented virtuality" as this is more a reality feedback to the virtual world than a real world getting augmented by virtual elements. What if I now include the player (via Kinect image and, let's say, a hat on his head) in the game? Augmented virtuality+reality? Any generic term?

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer-mediated_reality), I get that image:

[image: Mediated reality subsets]

From what I understand, this only classify situations where some kind of display integrates reality and modifies it (adding, removing, modifying objects). That does not include reality getting modified by a virtual application.

I would appreciate if someone can provide some kind of clarification on the matter ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [adapted milgrams VR-AR continuum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Adapted_milgrams_VR-AR_continuum.png) should help you take a decision.
Indeed, it seems that there are too many terms used to express AR/VR/MR(Mixed Reality) domains.

In your use case I would maybe use another term instead of Augmented Virtuality and the reason is the following:

> this is more a reality feedback to the virtual world

Even if the augmentation happens in the virtual world, the action that triggers the augmentation happens in the real world, therefore the term should contain "reality" also. On the other hand Augmented Virtuality + Reality is too heavy...

I think the best term to express your use case is Mediated Reality [ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer-mediated_reality ].

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll probably pick "mediated reality" then.
I'll still let the question opened for some days to see if someone else is willing to provide input.